# Encapsulation violation

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I was going through a question and here the answer says that `Encapsulation is being violated`

```
class car
{ 
    int speed;
    public : int* getSpeed()
    { 
        return &speed; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    car c;
    int *ptr=c.getSpeed();
    return 0;
}
```

But I really don't see how that is happening. Getters and Setters actually provide encapsulation.

Comment: Where is the question whose answer says that?

Comment: Information crosses borders all the time. The proper questions to ask are: (1) What is the goal? What tasks need to be done? What is to be accomplished? and (2) How to accomplish that, while minimizing the possibility of misuse (e.g. "encapsulation violation")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Returning a pointer to an internal variable of a class is an encapsulation violation, once you have that pointer, you can modify the `speed` variable inside of `car`.

To avoid that, return the value of `speed`.

```
class car
{ 
    int speed;
    public : int getSpeed()
    { 
        return speed; 
    }
};
```

Comment: In an ideal world nothing but `car` would ever know the value of speed. So this is still a violation. It's just not as nasty since you can now set a breakpoint and see when the encapsulation is being violated.

Comment: @candied_orange I use my encapsulated car as a black box.  I know nothing about its internals, but I can nevertheless read the speed on the tacho. It's part of the expectations for any car to provide for speed information in its interface.  I think that `int getSpeed()` is exactly that, and totally legit. It doesn't break encapsulation, since I could tomorrow decide to represent internally the speed completely differently and make a calculation (e.g. `int angular_velocity, wheel_diameter;` ).

Comment: @Christophe that's as bad as claiming it's ok to make the speed attribute public because you never use it. Even in python that wouldn't be ok.

Comment: @candied_orange so, how could an external class interact with the `Car` if it isn't allowed to ask any information?   Take the example of a simulation engine: how could you update the position of the Car if the Car can't be asked for its speed, if the Car doen's know anything about topology, and no class bcould ask neither the Map nor the Car the current position?

Comment: @Christophe if car is an actual object, and not just an over decorated data structure, you don't ask it anything. You tell it to do things. It does them. It's called [tell, don't ask](https://wiki.c2.com/?TellDontAsk).

Comment: @candied_orange thank you, but I still didn't get how a car do anything useful in interaction with other objects, in absence of any mutual feedback because every object is only allow to do things.  How does the car know that going straight away it will reach the end of the street and crash into a house, if neither the street nor the house can tell their position and the car does'nt know its own?  But there may be a misunderstanding here:  OP doesn't ask about the principle of least knowledge, but about encapsulation, i.e. providing a public interface and isolating the internal details.

Comment: This is about encapsulation. Getters and setters don't provide encapsulation. They just tattle on you when you break it. Real encapsulation doesn't tolerate logic being done on internal state outside of the object. If something needs to be done with the cars speed you send a message to car. Car can send the result of that to anything. But you don't ask car to give away it's private info.

Comment: @Christophe if a house has a crumple factor and a car has speed the object oriented design for a crash isn't for either to have getters. It's for one to send a crash message to the other with what the crash message needs. Done this way the house doesn't even need to keep a crumple factor as its internal state. It simply needs a way to calculate it. That ensures the independence of their design. Car makes it's need for a crumple factor explicit without insisting that it knows where to get it. House doesn't have to know what to do with the results. Car is free to send those results elsewhere.

Comment: @Christophe conversely, car can send a crash message to house, not with speed, but with momentum, since the house doesn't care about speed. House is free to express what it really needs to know in a crash regardless of what car's internal state design is.

Answer (score 5):

geocodezip's [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/412337/encapsulation-violation/412338#412338) is correct.

Any class member exposed through public functions as a non `const` reference (pointers are just another form of reference) violates encapsulation.

There are more ways to guarantee encapsulation besides the code shown by geocodezip:

- Use a `const` pointer

  ```
  public : const int* getSpeed() {
        // ^^^^^ prevents the value of speed getting changed through the pointer
        return &speed; 
  }
  ```
- Use a `const` reference

  ```
  public : const int& getSpeed() {
        // ^^^^^ prevents the value of speed getting changed through the reference
        return speed; 
  }
  ```

Using these from above won't have much impact with a simple `int` variables, but may have advantages for more complex scenarios.

E.g. the pointer variant allows to return a `nullptr` to indicate that there's an optional or uninitialized value.

In a similar manner `const` references allow to return something like an `empty` value type instead of the direct reference to the member (such things like `empty` value types should follow the *Flyweight Design Pattern*).

Comment: The const pointer or reference have the advantage of avoiding the external world to interfere in internal business of the class.  It nevertheless weakens the encapsulation since it forces you to maintain internally an int so that you can return its reference.  Furthermore, it forces you to always maintain this int, because once the reference is out, it could be used anytime.

Comment: @Christophe I don't (fully) get your point. Isn't the main goal to prevent directly changing the data from outside of the class? Using the `const` variants just allow to directly _observe_ how data is changed inside of that class. But you're right insofar, that those references need to refer to some particular data member maintained inside of the class.

Comment: In my original comment I was asking about behaviour of removing the *const-ness* using `const_cast` and then changing the value after. I eventually tried it in a sandbox and the internal value is indeed changed, so protecting the internal value using a `const` reference is not completely safe. Working example is available [here](http://cpp.sh/9nhw2).

Comment: @Andy A cast would remove the constness, but that's something that should never be done. At least you can almost always undermine intended behaviors.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I haven't really programmed in C++ in production, how do you guard against that on actual projects? Do you forbid the usage of the `const_cast` function and enforce this rule in code-review, or perhaps even through some static analysis tool?

Comment: @Andy Something like that, yes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see, that works, I guess. Thanks for taking your time to explain. :)

Answer (score 0):

By returning a pointer to the private member of the class you are violating the encapsulation. Now anyone can access that memory location using pointer which shows contradicting behavior. Encapsulation means hiding data, Getters and setters don't always give encapsulation. If you want encapsulation then you have to use getters and setters in a specific way such data nothing in world can access your class members.